# How to resolve redirects from MediaWiki

Tags: redirect, mediawiki, mediawiki-api

I'm currently trying to read the content of a MediaWiki site for which I only know only a generic URL which would redirect me to the 'real' content:

e.g when I want to read the explainxkcd content for comic `2423`, I can use `2423` as a title and request

`https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&formatversion=2&format=json&titles=2423`

Which gives me

```
{
  "batchcomplete": true,
  "query": {
    "pages": [
      {
        "pageid": 23828,
        "ns": 0,
        "title": "2423",
        "revisions": [
          {
            "contentformat": "text/x-wiki",
            "contentmodel": "wikitext",
            "content": "#REDIRECT [[2423: Project Orion]]"
          }]}]}}
```

I can now parse `2423: Project Orion` from `"#REDIRECT [[2423: Project Orion]]"` and manually turn it into `titles=2423:_Project_Orion` giving me

`https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&titles=2423:_Project_Orion`

But this feels strange and uselessly manual. Unfortunately I'm not so much into MediaWiki or web APIs in general - can you give me a hint how I *should* come from

`2423` (a generic index I know)

to

`https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&titles=2423:_Project_Orion` (the URL I want to query)

without having to manually synthesize the title from the MediaWiki answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `&redirects=1` to your query string:

https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&formatversion=2&format=json&titles=2423&redirects=1

> [redirects](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query): Automatically resolve redirects in query+titles,
> query+pageids, and query+revids, and in pages returned by
> query+generator.
>
> Type: boolean (details)